# How to hook WinInet properly with multiple threads?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer-9, hook, bho

I've written a BHO for Internet Explorer that hooks WinInet to modify some HTTP requests from IE by redirecting them to an internal server.

It works fine when I open the first 3 tabs in IE as a new iexplore.exe process is created for each tab, each loading the BHO.

Troubles appear when there are more than 4 tabs: instead of creating a new iexplore.exe process, existing processes are re-used in different thread. I can either hook the same process multiple times (1 per thread), or just once. In both cases, crashes happen when tabs are closed.

Example: open tabs 1 (separate iepxlore.exe), 2 (separate iepxlore.exe), 3 (separate iepxlore.exe) and 4 (share iexplore with tab 1). Close tab 1. Refresh tab 4, IE crashes inside NDTDLL.DLL. The crash happen if i I don't do anything inside the hooked WinInet.ddl (just call the old function)

If I hook WinInet only once per iexplore.exe process, I cannot intercept requests in all tabs.

I'm wondering what is the best way to proceed. All examples I've found so far assume that there is 1 iexpolore.exe process per tab.

The WinInet hook code is based on a [Code Project example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38616/Retrieve-HttpOnly-Session-Cookie-in-WebBrowser), I just hook fewer functions.

It looks like a pointer to he old WinInet function, or to the one I created, is no longer valid.

Comment: How exactly are you hooking WinInet, and more importantly, why? What exactly are you trying to modify about WinInet's requests? Please be more specific.

Comment: Does it crash if you don't do anything in your hook function? In other words, is the crash related to the act of hooking itself or something your doing in the function?

Comment: @matthew: I'll try that. My assumption is that the crash is happening becasuse of the hook, but I need to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you took the majority of the sample code from codeproject.com, you have a serious cleanup issue.

So this is what happens:

1. When you open a tab, your BHO gets loaded.
2. The g_oHook object (static) gets initialized. Its initialization sets hooks in all modules (i.e. in all other DLL's currently in the process).
3. By setting hook, I mean modifying the entries in the IAT (Import Address Table). They now points to your functions within the DLL (remember: when you make a call from one DLL to another DLL, you go through the IAT(
4. You then close the tab. Your DLL is being unloaded.
5. The addresses in the IAT of ntdll.dll still points to the memory space in the old location of your own DLL, which doesn't exist now. At the first time IE tries to call one of those function you get a fault

In order to fix, you need to implement a cleanup logic in the destruction of CWininetHook::~CWininetHook. Just do what the constructor does, and return the original address.